# Regex for json schema pattern

Tags: json, regex, jsonschema

I would like to validate a human input in json schema with pattern, but I cannot figure out the regex for it.

Valid formats are:

"Joe":"day1","Mitch":"day2"

or

"Joe":"day1"

So any number of iterations of "somebody":"someday" separated with , (comma).

Invalid formats are:

"Joe":"day1","Mitch":"day2",

Or

"Joe":"day1";"Mitch":"day2"

Example Json schema (pattern is not working here):

```
{
    "title": "Test",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
"meeting_date": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Give me a name and a day with the following format: \"Joe\":\"day1\" ",
            "default": "",
            "pattern": "(\"\\w*\")(?::)(\"\\w*\")"
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you want validate `{"Joe":"day1","Mitch":"day2"}` or `{value: "\"Joe\":\"day1\",\"Mitch\":\"day2\""}`

Comment: I would like to validate "Joe":"day1","Mitch":"day2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution  https://regex101.com/r/vW8m6K/2/

```
^("\w+":"\w+",)*"\w+":"\w+"$
```

But it fails on extra spaces, for it test:

```
^("\w+"\s*:\s*"\w+"\s*(?:,\s*|$))+$
```

Comment: Extra space are not a problem, it is perfect. Thanks. Now I understand. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern acutally almost works. You just have to remove the backslashes in front of your quotation marks.

```
("\w*")(?::)("\w*")
```

You can test your Regex on https://regex101.com/ (or some simular website).

Comment: Well this does not check the comma separator and if there is no extra comma in the end. Added 2 invalid formats in the question.